# Getting concrete return type of delegate

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, delegates

How can I find the concrete type of of a type whose signature is `IEnumerable<Func<ITab>>`?

My constructor takes the aforementioned type in order to perform lazy loading. Essentially, only load the tab when required in order to cut down on startup time. However, each concrete `Tab` implementation is decorated by an attribute that signifies the tabs name. As I'm looping through my list I would like to get the delegates concrete type in order to get the attributes value.

I'm aware of `.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke").ReturnType`, but that returns `ITab`. I can only seem to find the concrete type by calling `Invoke()`.

Are there possibly any better ways of achieving lazy loading using delegates while accesing information related to each concrete type?

Comment: Use generics or attributes.

Comment: Side note: your question is almost the same as "how to know what Random.Next will return without calling it"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need to know the type of the Tab before you actually invoke the method which returns it? When it's returned you could just use `GetType()` and then find the Attribute. What if one of your functions could return different implementations of `ITab`? Especially if the right one would be picked from an outside source like a database or xml. That delegate needs to be invoked.

Comment: +1 - there is formally no way to know what function will return without calling it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov right, and even if he went through all the alternatives by parsing the method, it would be pretty useless.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are absolutely correct. This design makes little to no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you seem to combine/confuse two issues: One is (meta-)data *about* your tabs, the other is the speed optimization of the tab *loading* time. If you need to have metadata *now*, but the tab contents *later*, you’ll need to split them.

I.e. do not return `IEnumerable<Func<ITab>>`, return something like `IEnumerable<ITabInfo>`, with `ITabInfo` containing 1) the information about the tab you need immediately, and 2) the delegate to be called later to load the actual contents of the tab.

There is no way you can get “the type which a method *is going to return in some future invocation*”. That would amount to a crystal ball (imagine `return random.Next(2) == 0 ? (ITab)new TabTypeA() : (ITab)new TabTypeB();`).